# How to code the following statement in cplex?

Tags: set, cplex

Suppose we have two sets A and B and we want to produce set AB
A=[{1}, {2}, {3}];
B=[{4}, {5}];
result:
AB = [{1,4}, {2,4}, {3,4}, {1,5}, {2,5}, {3,5} ]

I think it can be done with two for in the execute environment, but it gives a message that it cannot add the set to the set.
Of course, I don't know if there is a code to do this outside of execute or not?

```
int u=1;
    execute{
    for(var t in A){
        for(var z in B){            
            temp.clear();
            temp.add(A[t]);
            temp.add(B[z]);
            AB[u]= temp;
            u = u+1;
        }   
    }   
    
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you can write

```
{int} A ={1,2,3};
{int} B={4,5};

tuple t
{
  int x;
  int y;
}

{t} AB=union(i in A) {<i,j> | j in B};

execute
{
  writeln(AB);
}
```

which gives

```
 {<1 4> <1 5> <2 4> <2 5> <3 4> <3 5>}
```

When you have n sets , then I would recommend scripting as in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/cartesianproduct.mod

```
// Cartesian product for an abritrary number of sets

    tuple Tset {
        {string} members;
    }
    {Tset} setOfTuples = {<{"1","2"}>,<{"4","5","6"}>,<{"8","9"}>};

    int dimresult=prod(i in 1..card(setOfTuples)) card(item(setOfTuples,i-1).members);

    {string} setPool[i in 1..dimresult]={}; // pool of sets
    {string} options[i in 1..card(setOfTuples)]=(item(setOfTuples,i-1).members);


    {Tset} result={};

    //For this particular example, the function needs to return:
    //{<{1,4,8}>,<{1,4,9}>,<{1,5,8}>,<{1,5,9}>,<{1,6,8}>,<{1,6,9}>,<{2,4,8}>,<{2,4,9}>,<{2,5,8}>,<{2,5,9}>,<{2,6,8}>,<{2,6,9}>}

    execute
    {

    options;

    function nextone(ndimension,sizes,e)
    {
     e[1]++;
     for(j=1;j<=ndimension;j++)
     {
       if (e[j]>= sizes[j] )
       {
         e[j]=0;
         e[j+1]++;   
       }
     }
     
    }


    var dim=setOfTuples.size;
    writeln("dim=",dim);
    var sizes=new Array(dim);
    var e=new Array(dim);
    var dimresult=1;
    for(var i=1;i<=dim;i++)
    {
        sizes[i]=Opl.item(setOfTuples,i-1).members.size;
        e[i]=0;
        dimresult*=sizes[i];
        writeln(sizes[i]);
    }

     

    for(var i=1;i<=dimresult;i++)
    {
       
       for(var j=1;j<=dim;j++)
       {
          write(e[j]," ");
          
          setPool[i].add(Opl.item(options[j],e[j]));
       }   
       writeln();
       nextone(dim,sizes,e);
       result.add(setPool[i]);
    }
    writeln(result);
}
```